# Is it possible to define a floating point constant (`equ`) in NASM?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, constants, nasm

In NASM, it's possible to define integer constants (`equ`), however, doing the same with floating point values causes an error:

```
section .data
    c1 equ 3       ; ok
    v2 dq  3.14    ; ok
    c2 equ 3.14    ; not ok: `my.asm:7: error: expression syntax error`
```

is it possible to define a floating point constant?

I've check the [manual](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4), but there's very little information.

Comment: The `equ` directive defines symbols.  The value of a symbol is an address or an integer of the same size as an address.  So no floats for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `equ` doesn't work with non-integers. As fuz put it nicely:

> The `equ` directive defines symbols. The value of a symbol is an address or an integer of the same size as an address.

Instead, you could use `%define c2 3.14` to get text substitution of the macro at every point where you use it.  (As opposed to `equ` which evaluates an expression once, at the location of the `equ`.)

That difference between `equ` and macros (including `%define`) matters for expressions like `.len equ $ - v2` (because `$` has a higher value later or in other sections), or involving something you change later with a `%assign`.  But it doesn't matter for numeric literal constants; they always evaluate the same way everywhere.